# Lost play store

Tags: google-play-store

I was trying to fix the 491 issue and apparently followed badadvice uninstalled and the entire Play Store app disappeared from my phone I can't seem to get it reinstalled help please

Comment: How was the Play Store deleted? Is your phone rooted? Are you certain it was deleted and not disable?

Comment: You can download it from one of the APK hosters, like ApkPure: https://apkpure.com/de/google-play-store/com.android.vending

Answer (score 1):

You may have disabled it. Please make sure you don't find Google Play Store in Settings>Apps and get back to us!